# Mysql: How to make a table visible in a sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Mysql(`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`), and I write such a query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id),
  (SELECT sum(click)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id),
  (SELECT sum(view)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id)
FROM shops
```

It just works well. But today, I meet a problem which need a sql like that:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id),
  (SELECT sum(click)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id),
  (SELECT sum(view)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id),
  (
    SELECT sum(count)
    FROM (
           SELECT
             max(id),
             sum(view) AS 'count'
           FROM items
           WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id
           GROUP BY items.cat_id) a
  )
FROM shops
```

Mysql gives `Unknown column 'shops.id' in 'where clause'`. So my question:

1. Why `shops.id` is visible in sub-query with one depth like `(SELECT sum(click) FROM items WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id)`, but not visible when comes to a sub-query with two depth?
2. Is there any way to make `shops.id` visible in a depth two query?

Comment: try add 'as' to shops 'FROM shops as sh', and change 'shops' in all subqery to 'sh'

Comment: @АлексейМокрев Not works.

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem,kindly mark it as an answer and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not an expert on this but I'll explain it from my best understanding.

There can be 2 types of subqueries:
1) Correlated and (2) Uncorrelated

Let's take an example from your question:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = 1)
from shops;
```

In above query, the subquery only uses the fields of table that is defined in `From` clause of that subquery only. This is the example of Uncorrelated subquery.

Now, let's see your actual query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM items
   WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id)
from shops;
```

Here,subquery uses `shops.id` which is not part of the tablespace define in subquery.

A subquery (or inner SELECT statement) is correlated when the value it produces depends on a value produced by the outer SELECT statement that contains it.

Here, outer part of the subquery is table `shops`, which is visible to the subquery.

Now, let's go to the real question:

```
select
 (
    SELECT sum(count)
    FROM (
           SELECT
             max(id),
             sum(view) AS 'count'
           FROM items
           WHERE items.shop_id = shops.id
           GROUP BY items.cat_id) a
  )
FROM shops;
```

Here, subquery is itself inside `From` clause. `From` clause is use to fetch the table on which the different operations will be performed. But here `From` clause itself dependent on the outer select, which shouldn't be the case.

Hence, `shops.id` is not visible in the last subquery.

I hope this make some sense to you.

Comment: Is there any way to make a table visible in an uncorrelated table?

Comment: Can you please provide table schema with some sample data and the results that you want to display? That'll be really helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query as bellow

```
SELECT s.*,
COUNT(i.shop_id) total_count,
SUM(i.`view`) total_views,
SUM(i.click) total_clicks,
COALESCE(c.group_sum,0) group_sum
FROM shops s
JOIN items i ON i.shop_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN   (
    SELECT a.shop_id,SUM(a.count) group_sum
    FROM (
           SELECT shop_id,cat_id,MAX(id),SUM(`view`) AS `count`
           FROM items           
           GROUP BY shop_id,cat_id
   ) a
) c ON  s.id = c.shop_id
GROUP BY  s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create view and use in subquery

```
 create view group_count (shop_id,id,count) as 
(
SELECT
           shop_id as 'shop_id',
           max(id)  AS 'id',
           sum(view) AS 'count'
FROM items
GROUP BY items.shop_id,items.cat_id
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fc2962/1/0